# Add "1.00" to all existing Decimal Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I increase the price (decimal) by 1.00 for all products?

#### Product Record:

```
#<Product id: 87, name: "Product 1", price: #<BigDecimal:7f99954c11a8,'0.5E1',9(18)>, created_at: "2015-09-15 22:09:59", updated_at: "2015-09-15 22:09:59">
```

#### Attempt:

```
Product.update_all( price = price + 1.00 )
```

The problem is `price` is not defined for that particular product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think straightforward solution could work

```
Product.update_all("price = price + 1.00")
```

Comment: Be careful though, it will NOT trigger any validation of your Product model.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [increment!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21) method.

> Wrapper around increment that saves the record. This method differs from its non-bang version in that it passes through the attribute setter. Saving is not subjected to validation checks. Returns true if the record could be saved.

```
Product.increment!(:price, 1.00)
```